# Elmah not working on IIS7 server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I have Elmah running on my MVC 3 site, and have everything working on my local development machine.

However, now that I've moved my site to my production server, Elmah is not working. I am using the same SQL account (and connection string) on my live server as I'm using on my local machine.  The EF4 connection (same as Elmah) works just fine.

I don't see anything in the Even Logs or in SQL Profiler.  I don't see any errors in the SQL logs either.

Any ideas on what could be happening, or how I could troubleshoot this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Elmah + MVC + IIS7 does work, I'm using that combination.  What are you using for log storage? SQL or to file?

Comment: @JK - SQL Server 2005 database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ELMAH is using a HttpModule to log errors. For IIS6, HttpModules are registered under System.Web in the web.config file. However, for IIS7+, HttpModules should be registered under the system.webserver namespace. The embedded development web server will use the IIS6 config.

IIS6:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

IIS7:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Perfect, this was the problem.  I couldn't find this anywhere, thank you for your help!

Comment: Great answer :) Fixed my problem too. Just a side note I wish to add in case you also want to see the error log page "elmah.axd".  You also have to register the httpModule that handles elmah.axd under <system.webServer> instead of under <system.web> because of the new iis 7 integrated mode. In Integrated mode, ASP.NET handler mappings must be specified in the unified <system.webServer>/<handlers>. See http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/243/aspnet-integration-with-iis-7/