# Elmah not working on live site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, elmah

I am using elmah with an asp.net mvc 3 site and it works fine locally but when I upload it to my shared hosting site(iis 7) it does not seem to log any of the errors.

I used nuget to grab the library and I was under the assumption that it set up all the stuff in the web.config that it needs.

So I have no clue what I am missing and why it does not show up.

Edit

here is everything elmah I have

```
    <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
          <elmah xdt:Transform="Replace">
            <errorMail from=""
                   to=""
                   cc=""
                   subject=""
                   async="true"
                   smtpPort="26"
                   smtpServer=""
                   userName=""
                   password="" />
            <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" logPath="~/App_Data" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" />
            <errorFilter>
          <test>
            <equal binding="HttpStatusCode" value="404" type="Int32" />
          </test>
        </errorFilter>
        <security allowRemoteAccess="0" />
      </elmah>
    </configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>

    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
          <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
          <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      </modules>
      <handlers>
          <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
      </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Not sure is you've seen this, may be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387652/elmah-not-working-on-iis7-server

Comment: where are you storing the logs? sql, sqlite?

Comment: @naveen - sql same connection string is being used in local and live.

Comment: @chobo2: sounds stupid to ask this to a 4k member. but are you sure you created the relevant table and three sps as required?

Comment: @naveen - Yep I have ELMAH_Error table, ELMAH_GetErrorsXml, ELMAH_GetErrorXml and ELMAH_LogError SPS. Sigh I seem to always get this problem when I use elmah and try to go to live. It never seems to work for me(usually forget to set it up for iis 7) thought this time since I used nuget I would have no problems.

Comment: @chobo2: security allowRemoteAccess="0" :)

Comment: @ naveen - Ya I changed it to allow me to see it on the live site. However I guess I have to look at how to allow me to look it at on my live site but stop other people from going to it. I thought that in older versions I was able to load it up in local host and look at through that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have downloaded it with NuGet you should have all the config sections ready. 
Anyway, Try and check your `system.webServer` section:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
      <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: @LeftyX - I see that it has one for iis 6 as well. Do they conflict with each other? Like do I need to remove the iis 6 stuff?

Comment: @LeftyX - Do I need to setup anything special in my ms sql 2008 database(a permission maybe) other than the database table and the 3 sps?

Comment: @chobo2: Have you got the connection string (silly question)? <elmah>
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString"/>
</elmah>

Comment: @chobo2: you must be sure that the user (executing the worker process) can execute stored procedures.

Comment: @LefyX - Never mind. I don't know why I did not look right away but I looked in the database table and it is storing the records. I think what is happening is I was trying to look at the live ones through my local host but there not on the same application and host so they don't get shown. Guess something is still wrong with the email though as they don't send. I got to look into that I think that maybe threw me off.

Comment: @chobo2: Ok. Glad I've helped in some ways :-)